# Converting words in a file into a list in Python

Tags: python, file

This is not a general question. I was doing the MIT OCW 6.00 question 5 on http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-00-introduction-to-computer-science-and-programming-fall-2008/assignments/pset5.pdf

They use Python 2.x whereas I downloaded Python 3.4 which I believe may be the problem, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

I'm working on a function called `is_valid_word`

```
def is_valid_word(word, hand, word_list):
    """
    Returns True if word is in the word_list and is entirely
    composed of letters in the hand. Otherwise, returns False.
    Does not mutate hand or word_list.

    word: string
    hand: dictionary (string -> int)
    word_list: list of lowercase strings
    """
    hand_copy = hand.copy()
    if word not in word_list:
        return False
    for char in word:
        if char not in hand_copy:
            return False
        else:
            hand_copy[char] -= 1
        if hand_copy[char] < 0:
            return False
    return True
```

The test cases are here:

```
def test_is_valid_word(word_list):
    """
    Unit test for is_valid_word
    """
    failure=False
    # test 1
    word = "hello"
    hand = get_frequency_dict(word)

    if not is_valid_word(word, hand, word_list):
        print ("FAILURE: test_is_valid_word()")
        print ("\tExpected True, but got False for word: '" + word + "' and hand:", hand)

        failure = True

    # test 2
    hand = {'r': 1, 'a': 3, 'p': 2, 'e': 1, 't': 1, 'u':1}
    word = "rapture"

    if  is_valid_word(word, hand, word_list):
        print ("FAILURE: test_is_valid_word()")
        print ("\tExpected False, but got True for word: '" + word + "' and hand:", hand)

        failure = True        

    # test 3
    hand = {'n': 1, 'h': 1, 'o': 1, 'y': 1, 'd':1, 'w':1, 'e': 2}
    word = "honey"

    if  not is_valid_word(word, hand, word_list):
        print ("FAILURE: test_is_valid_word()")
        print ("\tExpected True, but got False for word: '"+ word +"' and hand:", hand)

        failure = True                        

    # test 4
    hand = {'r': 1, 'a': 3, 'p': 2, 't': 1, 'u':2}
    word = "honey"

    if  is_valid_word(word, hand, word_list):
        print ("FAILURE: test_is_valid_word()")
        print ("\tExpected False, but got True for word: '" + word + "' and hand:", hand)

        failure = True

    # test 5
    hand = {'e':1, 'v':2, 'n':1, 'i':1, 'l':2}
    word = "evil"

    if  not is_valid_word(word, hand, word_list):
        print ("FAILURE: test_is_valid_word()")
        print ("\tExpected True, but got False for word: '" + word + "' and hand:", hand)

        failure = True

    # test 6
    word = "even"

    if  is_valid_word(word, hand, word_list):
        print ("FAILURE: test_is_valid_word()")
        print ("\tExpected False, but got True for word: '" + word + "' and hand:", hand)
        print ("\t(If this is the only failure, make sure is_valid_word() isn't mutating its   inputs)")        

        failure = True        

    if not failure:
        print ("SUCCESS: test_is_valid_word()")
```

The only cases I am getting a `FAILURE` are the ones that should return `True`. When I removed

```
if word not in word_list:
    return False
```

I got a `SUCCESS`. However this should not be the case because one of the requirements is to check if the word is in the `word_list`. The test cases did not include a case where a word is not in the word list but when I included one, that printed `FAILURE`. The problem I believe is with the list `word_list`. 
It comes from here:

```
WORDLIST_FILENAME = "words.txt"

def load_words():
    """
    Returns a list of valid words. Words are strings of lowercase letters.

    Depending on the size of the word list, this function may
    take a while to finish.
    """
    print ("Loading word list from file...")
    # inFile: file
    inFile = open(WORDLIST_FILENAME, 'rb', 0)
    # wordlist: list of strings
    wordlist = []
    for line in inFile:
       wordlist.append(line.strip().lower())
    print ("  ", len(wordlist), "words loaded.")
    return wordlist
```

The line assigning `inFile` is where I believe the problem may lie, but I don't know how to fix it.

EDIT: I just realized all the words in the file are in uppercase but the test cases are in lower case. However, the

```
wordlist.append(line.strip().lower())
```

should make the words in the file lower case right?

Comment: Could this be a `str`/`bytes` conversion difference thing?

Comment: Why not try it in. 2.x and see what happens?

Comment: As of Python 3, string literals like `word = "evil"` create str objects. Opening a file in binary mode ensures that it gives bytes objects. These are not equal.

Comment: So should I use str() to represent the lines in the file? If I change the for loop in `load_words()` to `for str(line) in inFile:`

Comment: Open your file in `'r'` mode instead of `'rb'` and you'll get strings back. If your file contains something other than pure ascii, set the encoding appropriately.

Comment: I tried that earlier, but then I get an error that says `can't have unbuffered text I/O`

Comment: Your third argument, 0, sets a buffering policy that's not allowed for non-binary input. Set your buffering policy appropriately, as described in the docs: https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#open

You can probably just omit that parameter and run with the default value.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper Can you post your comment as an answer?